# Developer Story should show the missing details

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

I have this warning sign in my Developer Story saying I need to fill more information. But it does not show where exactly the information is required.

Can you make the warning sign tell me *which* information I should add?

Comment: This would be super useful - my story is telling me information is missing but I cannot for the life of me see what it is